# Fast min-max AABB collision detection

Tags: javascript, geometry, collision-detection

So I wonder, what's the fastest way to detect an AABB vs AABB collision, where an AABB's structure is based on a min point and a max point?

Javascript:

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
}


function AABB(min, max) {
  this.min = min || new Point();
  this.max = max || new Point();
}

AABB.prototype.intersects = function(other) {
  ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found it out o_O

This is the fastest solution:

```
AABB.prototype.intersects = function(other) {
  return !(
    this.max.X < other.min.X || 
    this.max.Y < other.min.Y || 
    this.min.X > other.max.X || 
    this.min.Y > other.max.Y
  );
}
```